# virtual mail replication

Tags: email, replication

I have 2 servers that have mail server, both have mysql, dovecot, postfix installed. One of the servers is a Master, second Slave, there is database replication done which works great however mails are not replicated as they are held as files. How should I replicate emails from the Master server into the Slave server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dependent on server load:
try to use drdb or to store emails in DB
and replicate db

Answer (score 0):

Use Dovecot's dsync utility

I've tried following the instructions on [Jarasyola's blog](https://jarasyola.blogspot.com/2016/09/replicating-emails-between-two-mail.html) but I'm having some teething problems with my specific configuration.